# How to debug connections from virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a website (say, `test.com`) with PHP code running on Ubuntu with nginx. I can debug it via PhpStorm and Xdebug 2.

And now I want to debug it (specifically, use breakpoints in PhpStorm) when requests are going from my VMware machine with Windows 10. For example, I can run `test.com` in guest machine's browser and it will show the website, but at the same time Xdebug or PhpStorm don't stop at breakpoints.

My `/etc/hosts` contains the following string:

```
192.168.50.11 test.com
```

And here is my `20-xdebug.ini` config:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log="/var/log/nginx/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

**UPDATE:** As Eugene Morozov suggested in comments, I tried to change `xdebug.remote_host`. Here is excerpt from `ip address` on Ubuntu host:

```
3: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.162.1/24 brd 172.16.162.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.212.1/24 brd 192.168.212.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So I tried to set `remote_host` to both `172.16.162.1` and `192.168.212.1` with no luck (each time I restarted PHP-service and tried to set corresponding IP to DBGp Proxy setting in PHPStorm).

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks for commenters: I updated Xdebug to 3rd version and now it's working with VM connections too.

Comment: In PHP, it's the debugger that initiates a connection to the IDE, not the other way around. You need to set xdebug.remote_host to an IP/hostname the virtual machine can use to connect to the host. For VMware, usually it's an IP of the VMnet* adapter your VM is using.

Comment: @Eugene Morozov, Please look at updated part of question, may be I have misunderstood which IP to use

Comment: Uh-oh. I think I've gotten the setup wrong. So, your host is Ubuntu, and the guest is Windows? And the web server is on the host, while PhpStorm is in the VM? Usually, it's the other way around. Okay then. By default, guests in VMware are using NAT networking, which means that you cannot connect to them directly. You need to create a host-only network for the VM and then use the guest IP assigned by this network as `remote_host` instead. You can use `telnet IP 9003` on host while `Listening for PHP debug connections` is enabled in PhpStorm to find out whether the IP is correct or not

Comment: No) Everything development-related is running on Ubuntu-host - nginx, PHP, xdebug, PHPStorm. I just need to send HTTP requests to my web-app from Windows VM.

Comment: Please upgrade to Xdebug 3 too, and see what xdebug_info() tells you in a request that you're trying to debug. Xdebug 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: @qloq *"Everything development-related is running on Ubuntu-host - nginx, PHP, xdebug, PHPStorm. I just need to send HTTP requests to my web-app from Windows VM"* Then as far as I understand it should work: the source of the request does not matter here. It may not stop because Xdebug does not see the "debug me" flag that PhpStorm sets or you.

Comment: @qloq I suggest you upgrade Xdebug to v3 (as Derick suggested), update Xdebug config as needed (check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and have only Xdebug v3 params (because right now you are mixing v2 and v3 params there). For example `xdebug.start_with_request` is for v3 -- v2 should use `xdebug.remote_autostart`. Then show `xdebug_info()` output when it works and when it's not. Right now I think Xdebug simply does not see the Xdebug's "debug me" cookie/request parameter -- try using Xdebug browser extension to set the cookie.

Comment: @qloq BTW -- will it work if you insert `xdebug_break();` programmatic breakpoint in your PHP code? If it works then it has to be the "debug me" flag: either use t .. or make sure that Xdebug tries to debug every single request (`xdebug.start_with_request` for v3).

Comment: I updated post. Please, someone, make an answer post, I will accept it and we can close this question.